# Stripe Flutter can't display payment in IOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I'm working Flutter Stripe with this library : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe.

This is the function from my bloc to create successfully payment intent and display the payment sheet.

```
paymentSink.add(Status.Loading);
logData(key, 'Stripe Pay');
//create payment intent
var response = await paymentRepository.createPaymentIntent(200, 'USD');
paymentSink.add(Status.Successful);
var paymentIntentData = json.decode(response.body);
await stripe.initPaymentSheet(
    paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
  applePay: true,
  googlePay: true,
  style: ThemeMode.dark,
  testEnv: true,
  merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
  customerId: paymentIntentData!['customer'],
  paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData['client_secret'],
  customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentData['ephemeralKey'],
));
//display payment sheet
await displayPaymentSheet();
if(isSuccessPaid){
  logData(key, 'isSuccessPaid: $isSuccessPaid');
  //handle result after payment successfully
}
```

and this is the display payment sheet function

```
try {
  await stripe.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) {
    isSuccessPaid = true;
  }).onError((error, stackTrace){
    GetIt.I<AppSnackBar>().show(error.toString());
    logData(key,error.toString());
  });
} catch (e) {
  GetIt.I<AppSnackBar>().show(e.toString());
  logData(key, '$e');
}
```

The problem is Android simulator works perfectly like this

[image]

but the IOS simulator can't display it and the terminal shows the errors like this
[image]

I don't know this is the platform error or just the simulator problem.Anyone got problem like this?Please help.Thanks!

Comment: I would guess the issue is you try to display the sheet immediately after initialising it and that might cause a race condition or something. If you change the logic so the `initPaymentSheet` happens as soon as the view is loaded, and only call `displayPaymentSheet` after a button is actually tapped for example, does that help?

Comment: i'm not sure but i know your point.I add await before the initPaymentSheet but i guess it didn't call displayPaymentSheet immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Thursday 14 Apr 2022
For someone got same problem like me , i just want to share basic answer like this:

```
await stripe.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    applePay: true,
    googlePay: true,
    testEnv: true,
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
    merchantDisplayName: 'Prospects',
    customerId: paymentIntentData!['customer'] ?? 'Customer',
    paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
  ));
```

customerId and paymentIntentClientSecret mustn't be null so check null safety carefully and the response data must has the client_secret field